# Podfile not recognized in Xcode Directory

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, zsh

I am attempting to use CocoaPods for the first time in Xcode, and I am running into an error when trying to install the pod.

I have the latest version of Cocoapods installed.  I use the terminal to navigate to the folder for my Xcode project and use `pod init` to create a Podfile.

After that, I open the Podfile, include all the necessary code to install the pod I'm looking for, then, in the same directory, use `pod install`.

At this point, I get the following error:

`` [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory. ``

When I try `pod init` again, however, It tells me:

`[!] Existing Podfile found in directory`

Thus, it seems to be able to see the Podfile, but it won't recognize it when I try to install it.

Here is the Podfile itself, if that helps:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Flash Chat iOS13' do

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat iOS13

  pod 'CLTypingLabel'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the issue.  One of my directories had a pretty absurd name, using both Japanese characters and numbers in a Japanese style.  I changed the name of the directory and it found the Podfile.  I hope this helps someone in the future!